# Close lightbox with click on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I;m doing a lightbox tutorial from w3school (http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) 
what im trying to do is to close the lightbox when the user clicks on the screen, but only when it click outside of the img's.

With this piece of code that i'm using, it don't matter where the user clicks, it always closes the lightbox....is there a way to fix this.

```
$( 'body').on('click', function(event) {
     closeModal();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', function(event) {
    closeModal();
});

$('#yourLightboxId').on('click', function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent that the click event reaches the lightbox's parents, which includes the `body`.

Comment: Thank you lucas..I try this solution and i also added the closeModal() function..but I still have the same problem. this is how the function looks
$('#myModal').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeModal();
}); any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't add the `closeModal()` line inside your modal's `click` event. `stopPropagation` is preventing the `click` event to reach `body` but you're still closing the modal inside the modal's click event itself. Remove this line and it should work.

Comment: But if i don't add the closeModal(), how am i going to close the lightBox...im a little confuse

Comment: It will remain in the `body` click listener. I'll update my answer with the whole code as I think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the click listener registered on the `body` like so:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
    closeModal();
});
```

And, as a simple solution, attach a click listener to the lightbox itself to capture and swallow any click events when it is the target.

```
$('.lightbox').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`stopPropagation` will prevent the event from bubbling up to other listeners, e.g. the `document.body`. This will ensure that `body`'s listener won't fire.

Substitute `.lightbox` with the unique selector for your lightbox container.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.yourclassoflightbox').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```